# Docker could not start because I do not have enough memory. How to solve it?

Tags: docker

I got into a HTML/CSS/JavaScript course and I need Docker Desktop installed an functionally on my laptop. The problem is that I can not start it because I do not have enough memory, the error is appearing every time when I try to start it. I have tried to solve it by lowering the settings of the Docker Engine, free up some memory with RAMMap and turn Windows to performance mode, but unfortunately the error is still here.
The laptop that I work on has only 2 GB of RAM. Is there a solution to start Docker?

Comment: You don't need Docker to work with those technologies; IMHO it adds a lot of complexity for almost no value.  The only host-side dependency you should actually need for front-end development is the [Node](https://nodejs.org/) Javascript engine and this is fairly easy to install if you don't already have it.

Comment: For our days 2 GB is a really, really small amount of ram, you need at least 4 for work(excluding heavy application. ide, image/video editors and so on).

Comment: 2 GB of RAM is barely enough to run Windows itself. You're not going to be able to run Docker (or much of anything else). How do you solve it? Install more memory or buy a newer laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Delete both `%appdata%\Docker` and `%appdata%\Docker Desktop` and run Docker as Administrator

Comment: Better add code formatting to the answer. It's not clear where the paths start/end.